# WPF IrfanView-style image cropping control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, controls, crop

I am looking for a control for cropping images as it is in eg. IrfanView (Drawing rectangle with possibility to move individual sides). I have not found anything like this. Does such control exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at the [`CroppedBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.croppedbitmap.aspx) class, there are several tutorials out there explaining how to use it. [This example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23158/A-Photoshop-like-Cropping-Adorner-for-WPF) uses it with an adorner in order to visually select the area that should be cropped.